# Postgresql: How to perform cross db queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, psql, rails-postgresql

I currently have 2 same schema databases (1 for staging and 1 for production). One issue I had was by accident the staging was used with real production data, I simply can't manually input it on the browser since there's over a hundred data I need to transfer and an incremental dump wont work since it would cause conflict with the unique IDs existing.

One idea I had in mind was to do something like

Insert into  post values (select * from staging_db);

But from what I've seen psql 8.4.13 doesn't seem to support this feature compared to mysql. Is there any other way I can do the transfer?

Also I am doing the app on rails 3, if psql is out then perhaps some rails way can do this?

Comment: Just take the dump of the source database and then go to the target application, start the postgressql console and run the dump of source database to the target application database.

Comment: You can with http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/postgres-fdw.html but you will need postgresql 9.3. BTW you should consider upgrading anyway as 8.4 is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

`COPY` the data out to a file, then back again.

Assuming you're using the `psql` client:

```
\c staging_db
\copy (select col1, col2, col3 from the_table where ....) to 'newvalues.csv'
\c production_db
\copy the_table(col1, col2, col3) from 'newvalues.csv'
```

Note that the column-list should omit the generated ID column, so that the `\copy ... from ...` will force the generation of new IDs.

This won't work if your new data is in more than just the one table; you'll have to write a script/tool to extract it and re-insert it.